# Web form Report crashes upon adding date field

Tags: entities, webforms

I'm using the Webform Report module (version 7.x-1.0) alongside Webform module (7.x-4.16) on Drupal 7.22. When I add Date column to Webform report then save it and view ,Report crashes with message ..website is currently unable to handle this request.HTTP ERROR 500. no matter what format(yyyy/mm/dd..) I enter in date field or leave it empty same happens, If I create report in View by adding all fields including Date fields it works. Also in Webform-Results -Table it works.
Any suggestions..
Also can we in drupal 7 enter date and time both in same textbox so it lands in db in one field or it must be separated as I see drupal has it as separate types?

[image: date field in Web report]

Thank you,
Nikola

Comment: Drupal ***7.22***, really? What is stopping you from upgrading to something like 7.5x (and then try again)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not in situation where we can easily update Drupal because of work environment, the solution was forena reports, which offer full freedom in sql queries(not limited by Webform report or Views limits when creating sql) also result(report) based on query can be shown in drupal interface, just needs some more css adjustment in table header/table data widths for columns

Nikola